# How do I convert pounds to kg in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run the code below in Ruby, I get an error that says: `ex5.rb:3:in '< main >': undefined local variable or method 'cm' for main:Object < NameError >`

What am I doing wrong?

```
name = 'Chris Hanson'
height = 60 * cm 
cm = 2.54
weight = 180 % kg 
kg = 2.2
eyes = 'Brown'
teeth = 'White'
hair = 'Black'

puts "Let's talk about #{name}."
puts "He's #{height} cm tall."
puts "He's #{weight} kg heavy."
puts "He's got #{eyes} eyes and #{hair} hair."
puts "His teeth are usually #{teeth} depending on the coffee."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is not declaring the variables before using them. Look the order I used (for both 'cm' and 'kg' variables):

```
name = 'Chris Hanson'
cm = 2.54
height = 60 * cm
kg = 2.2
weight = 180 % kg
eyes = 'Brown'
teeth = 'White'
hair = 'Black'

puts "Let's talk about #{name}."
puts "He's #{height} cm tall."
puts "He's #{weight} kg heavy."
puts "He's got #{eyes} eyes and #{hair} hair."
puts "His teeth are usually #{teeth} depending on the coffee."
```

This seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Ruby may only be referenced after you have declared them. Try moving the variable "height" below "cm". Likewise, you should place "weight" below "kg".